# Is there a better way to define these funtions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

There has to be a better way of doing this.
I feel like I'm repeating myself.
Can anyone help? I'm a bit new to this. Is there some way that these different data functions and variables into a class that I can inherit from?
Thanks in advance!

```
import { Guild, GuildMember, TextChannel } from "discord.js"
import mafiaRoleSchema from "./models/mafiaRole-schema"
import willSchema from "./models/will-schema"

interface data<type>{
    // MemberID: message
    [key: string]: type
}

let willData = {} as data<string>

export async function setWillData(key : GuildMember, value: string) {
    willData[key.id] = value
    await willSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: key.id
    }, {
        _id: key.id,
        value
    }, {
        upsert: true
    })
}

export async function getWillData(key : GuildMember): Promise<string | null>{
    let data = willData[key.id]

        if(!data){
            const results = await willSchema.findById(key.id)
            if (!results){
                return null
            }

            const {text} = results
            data = willData[key.id] = text
        }
    return data
}

let mafiaRoleData = {} as data<string>

export async function setmafiaRoleData(key : GuildMember, value: string) {
    mafiaRoleData[key.id] = value
    await mafiaRoleSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: key.id
    }, {
        _id: key.id,
        value
    }, {
        upsert: true
    })
}
export async function getmafiaRoleData(key : GuildMember): Promise<string | null>{
    let data = mafiaRoleData[key.id]

        if(!data){
            const results = await mafiaRoleSchema.findById(key.id)
            if (!results){
                return null
            }

            const {text} = results
            data = mafiaRoleData[key.id] = text
        }
    return data
}

let welcomeData = {} as data<[TextChannel, string]>

export async function setwelcomeData(key : Guild, value: [TextChannel, string]) {
    welcomeData[key.id] = value
    const [target, text] = value
    await mafiaRoleSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: key.id
    }, {
        _id: key.id,
        text,
        channelId: target.id
    }, {
        upsert: true
    })
}

export async function getwelcomeData(key : Guild): Promise<[TextChannel, string] | null>{
    let data = welcomeData[key.id]

        if(!data){
            const results = await mafiaRoleSchema.findById(key.id)
            if (!results){
                return null
            }

            const {channelId, text} = results
            const channel = key.channels.cache.get(channelId) as TextChannel
            data = [channel, text]
        }
    return data
}
```

I've tried putting the functions into the interface. But that didn't work. I honestly don't know where to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it seems like a lot, but this isn't as bad as you think. Your welcome message code is sufficiently different than your other code, which merits it having its own functions.

As for the mafia and will data, you could do an abstraction kind of like this:

```
import mafiaRoleSchema from "./models/mafiaRole-schema"
import willSchema from "./models/will-schema"

interface Data<type>{
    // MemberID: message
    [key: string]: type
}

type Schema = typeof mafiaRoleSchema | typeof willSchema // this could be more generic if you have access to those types

class SchemaController {
  private schema: Schema
  private data: Data<string>

  constructor(schema: Schema) {
    this.schema = schema
    this.data = {}
  }

  async setData(key: GuildMember, value: string) {
    this.data[key.id] = value
    await this.schema.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: key.id
    }, {
        _id: key.id,
        value
    }, {
        upsert: true
    })
  }

  async getData(key : GuildMember): Promise<string | null> {
    let data = this.data[key.id]

      if(!data){
          const results = await this.schema.findById(key.id)
          if (!results){
              return null
          }

          const {text} = results
          data = this.data[key.id] = text
      }
  return data
}

const mafiaController = new SchemaController(mafiaRoleSchema)
const willController = new SchemaController(willSchema)
```